# iOS: Make navigation bar always visible in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have searched and searched and have been unable to find an answer to my problem.

I have a Table View Controller and I need the navigation bar to always be visible at the top of the screen and not scroll up along with the table view.  I've seen solutions suggesting I adjust the content inset, set it to translucent, etc.  None of those work.  If you can provide any solutions/suggestions I would be very appreciative!

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent=YES;

self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(44,0,0,0);
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets =  NO;

self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;


if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale > 1.0)
{
    [self->btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button@2x.png"]];
}
else
{
    [self->btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"]];
}

self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:69/255.0 green:189/255.0 blue:150/255.0 alpha:1.0];


[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bar_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];


NSLog(@"Loading up coupons");

MWRAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

if([g_categoryName isEqualToString: @"All"]){
    NSMutableArray *coupons = [appDelegate getAllCoupons];

    NSMutableArray *contests = [appDelegate getAllContests];

    NSArray *newArray=[contests arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:coupons];

    self.fetchedRecordsArray = newArray;
}
else {
    NSMutableArray *coupons = [appDelegate getCatCoupons];

    NSMutableArray *contests = [appDelegate getAllContests];

    NSArray *newArray=[contests arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:coupons];

    self.fetchedRecordsArray = newArray;
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Comment: show code of what you have done so far so we will know where it went wrong

Comment: These two things seem contradictory, "I need the navigation bar to always be visible at the top of the screen and scroll up along with the table view." If it scrolls with the table view, it won't always be visible, so which do you want?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant "And not scroll up along with the table view"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to embed your UITableViewController in an UINavigationControler.

Using Storyboard : select your UITableViewController, press Editor > Embed in > Navigation controller.

Or by code, create a UINavigationController and set your tableviewcontroller as its rootviewcontroller :

```
UINavigationController* aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourTableViewController];
```

and present aNavigationController instead of presenting yourTableViewController ;-)

ps: if yourTableViewController is not embeded in a navigation controller, then calling self.navigationController will just return nil and any action on it would be nil too.

Comment: I just tried your method, "Using Storyboard : select your UITableViewController, press Editor > Embed in > Navigation controller" and it did not work, same result.

Comment: @JasonHowell, that should have worked. What is "same result"? You never mention in your question what result you got in the first place.

Comment: @rdelmar the same result being when you scroll down on the table view the navigation bar stays at the top of the table view and eventually is no longer visible the further you go down the list.  I need that navigation bar to remain visible regardless of where you are on the list of the table view.

Comment: @JasonHowell, I'm not sure what you're doing then, because embedding your table view controller in a navigation controller should make the navigation bar stay at the top.

Comment: I did exactly what was described "Using Storyboard : select your UITableViewController, press Editor > Embed in > Navigation controller" and my navigation bar scrolls up along with the table view itself.  I performed that step, it built without issue and there was no change.  This TableView is load modally from a tab view, to shed some more light on the subject.

Comment: @JasonHowell, When you present your table view controller, are you presenting it, or the navigation controller that its embedded in? It should be the latter.

Comment: When the user clicks a button in the TabView it instantiates the TableViewController directly.   I changed this to load the navigation controller instead and voila, its working.  I feel very stupid right now, thank you all for your assistance, this is a huge relief!